# “Error no label add or removes specified” when trying to modify labels using Gmail's Ruby API

Tags: ruby, gmail-api

I've looked at https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/GmailV1/ModifyThreadRequest and the examples https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/update for Python and JS but can't figure out how to format the request properly in ruby.

I'm trying:

```
service.modify_thread('me',thread_id,{'add_label_ids'=>['UNREAD']})
```

and various other permutations of the object but can't get anything other than `Google::Apis::ClientError: invalidArgument: No label add or removes specified` in response.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you post a MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`modify_thread` expects a `Google::Apis::GmailV1::ModifyThreadRequest` object as third argument according to the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService#modify_thread-instance_method).

In the [source](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google%2FApis%2FGmailV1%2FModifyThreadRequest:update!) of the constructor of ModifyThreadRequest you can see that it looks for a key `:add_label_ids` in its arguments.

So if `modify_thread` creates the ModifyThreadRequest object itself then

```
service.modify_thread('me',thread_id, add_label_ids: ['UNREAD'])
```

should work. 
If that fails I would try

```
mtr = Google::Apis::GmailV1::ModifyThreadRequest.new(add_label_ids: ['UNREAD'])
service.modify_thread('me', thread_id, mtr)
```